# Why do exceptions not stop Akka Stream flow

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

I have a flow that relies on API responses. When the responses do not conform to what I expect an exception is thrown. This strategy works nicely for Spray and for direct method testing with specs2.

However, when I try to use streams with exception throwing modules the flow simply halts.

This is my flow:

```
 Source(() => file)
      .via(csvToSeq)
      .via(getFromElastic)
      .via(futureExtrtactor)
      .via(findLocaionOfId)
      .foreach(v => v.map(v => println("foreached", v)))
      .onComplete(_ => system.shutdown())
```

My strategy for this is using `map` for futures.

like so:

```
 val findLocaionOfId = Flow[Future[Seq[(String, JsValue)]]].map(future => future.map(jsSeq => {
      jsSeq.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case (x, i) => x._2.asJsObject.getFields("_source").flatMap(js => {
        js.asJsObject("Couldn't convert").getFields("externalId").map({
          case JsString(str) => {
              (i + 1, i == 0, js)
            }
            else (i, false, js)
          }
          case _ => (i, false, x)
        })
      })
      }
    }))
```

This is a potential exception thrower in a completely different location:

```
val encoded_url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")
```

Seems like I am missing something but can't see what. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific here.  What is the behavior that is currently happening and what would you prefer instead?  If a transform step is failing and that's stopping the rest of the flow, what would you prefer instead?  Providing that kind of specifics will help people craft a better answer for you.

Comment: In your `onComplete` you are disregarding the value of the `Try` that is supplied by using `_`. You should instead try matching on `Success` and `Failure` and seeing which you get. If a fail you should have the stack.

Comment: The program never terminates so oncomplete doesn't fire

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an issue that will be addressed once [Supervision for Akka Streams](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/15710) is implemented. Akka Streams are still "pre-experimental" so that feature has not been implemented yet, but is definitely planned to be included soon.

*// As of writing this comment current version is 1.0-M2 (preview milestone).*

Answer (score 3):

The thing i was missing was `mapAsync`.

changing the above function to:

```
val findLocaionOfId = Flow[Future[Seq[(String, JsValue)]]].mapAsync({...})
```

This way the futures are unwrapped and exceptions stop the program as expected.

Comment: Yes; when I read your question I was surprised to see Flow[Future]; It seemed redundant. (although there are select reasons why passing a Future down a Flow is warranted).

Comment: That's actually a very good point Tim. It wasn't clear to me how I unwrap a future and this is it. maybe I should post a new question /  answer set